# Using SQL If Statement In Newly Created Table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following table:

| ID | product_cat | transact_ type | qty | product_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ball Pen | Purchases | 15 | 10001 |
| 2 | Ball Pen | Sales | 15 | 10004 |
| 3 | Ball Pen | Purchases | 5 | 10001 |
| 4 | Eraser | Sales | 10 | 10004 |

I also have this SQL query this SQL query

```
With stock as (
    select product, product_code,
    sum(case when transact_type = 'Purchases' then qty else 0 end) as Purchases,
    sum(case when transact_type = 'Sales' then qty else 0 end) as Sales
    from stockcheck.sql_transactions 
    group by product_cat, product_code 
    order by product_cat
)
select stock.product_code, stock.product_cat, stock.Purchases, 
stock.Sales, (Purchases - Sales) as Balance,
stock.sql_product_tbl.mini_qty_alert
from stock
left join stockcheck.sql_product_tbl
on stock.product_code = stockcheck.sql_product_tbl.product_code
```

The above query converts the above table(a) into this table(b)

| product_code | product_cat | purchases | sales | balance | mini_qty_alert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | Ball Pen | 20. | 15. | 5. | 10 |

I want to modify the above SQL query to add another column to the second table(b) called remarks that will return "Order Now" if balance is less than mini_qty_alert. Thanks

So I have two separate tables in the DB schema called stockcheck. Within this schema are various tables that includes the two tables sql_transactions and sql_product_tbl indicated in the SQL query above.

Comment: Hi - so what is stopping you adding this column? What is your actual issue?

Comment: `stock.sql_product_tbl` should be `stockcheck.sql_product_tbl`. I recommend making liberal use of table aliases so you don't have to keep repeating long names like this.

Comment: WTP? `IF((purchases - sales) < mini_qty_alert, 'Order Now', '') AS Remarks`

Comment: You'll probably want to use `IFNULL(mini_qty_alert, some_default_value)` to handle the cases that don't have a matching row in `sql_product_tbl`.

Comment: Although I can't really imagine having transactions for products that aren't in the product table. Why are you using `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: There's no `product_cat` column returned by the `stock` CTE. Is `product` supposed to be `product_cat`? Why does the transactions table have the category? Shouldn't it just have a foreign key to the products table, and the category should be there?

Comment: @Barmar "IF((purchases - sales) < mini_qty_alert, 'Order Now', '') AS Remarks" Please where do I place this line? Should it come after the join line?

Comment: It goes in the `SELECT` list, just like any other column you want in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `IF` expression to the `SELECT` list

```
With stock as (
    select product_cat, product_code,
    sum(case when transact_type = 'Purchases' then qty else 0 end) as Purchases,
    sum(case when transact_type = 'Sales' then qty else 0 end) as Sales
    from stockcheck.sql_transactions 
    group by product_cat, product_code 
    order by product_cat
)
select s.product_code, s.product_cat, s.Purchases, 
    s.Sales, (s.Purchases - s.Sales) as Balance,
    p.mini_qty_alert, 
    IF(s.Purchase - s.Sales < IFNULL(p.mini_qty_alert, 10), 'Order Now', '') AS Remarks
from stock AS s
left join stockcheck.sql_product_tbl AS p on s.product_code = p.product_code
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Will give it a try now. I just read and see you are a Big Man is the game. I am really new. Accounting student trying to be YOU. . So pls pardon me for my naivety . Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am most grateful. God bless you